# module parse failed after adding the sass loaders

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, frontend

I'm following a beginner tutorial on webpack and I'm supposed to use sass in my project so I ran this command `npm i -D style-loader node-sass css-loader sass-loader` to install necessary loaders I needed. also, I added a test case to my rules array `{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
}`.I tried to run my application it gives me a sass error that I don't get 
[image: sass error]

My package.json
[image: Package.json]

My webpack.dev.js

```
// Allows us to override the default configs that comes with webpack
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode:'development',
  stats: 'verbose',
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test:'/\.js$/',
        exclude:/node_modules/,
        loader:"babel-loader"

    },
    {
      test: '/\scss$/',
      use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
    }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/client/views/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            // Simulate the removal of files
            dry: true,
            // Write Logs to Console
            verbose: true,
            // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,
            protectWebpackAssets: false
        })
  ]
};
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren’t you missing a dot in the regex (test) property of the loader?
/\.scss/

Inside webpack.dev.js

Comment: It worked Thank you. and I found that the $ needed to be edited .